# c++ mingw-64 winapi MENUITEMINFO добавить иконку

Tags: c++, winapi, g++, mingw-w64

windows 7,
mingw-w64 "g++ (i686-win32-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0"

Привет, учу winapi [menus](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/menurc/menus), хочу добавить иконку чекбокса(сняты и не снятый флажок) в меню, при компиляции ошибок не выводится, при запуске появляется системный значок чекбокса, вот код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resources.h"

HWND            g_hWnd;
HINSTANCE       g_hInst;

void funCreateMenu(HWND hWnd){
    HMENU menu          = CreateMenu();
    HMENU sub_menu      = CreateMenu();

    HBITMAP check   = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_MENU_OPEN_CHECK), IMAGE_BITMAP, SM_CXMENUCHECK, SM_CYMENUCHECK, 0);
    HBITMAP uncheck = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_MENU_OPEN_UNCHECK), IMAGE_BITMAP, SM_CXMENUCHECK, SM_CYMENUCHECK, 0);

    MENUITEMINFO mii_menu{0};
        mii_menu.cbSize         = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
        mii_menu.fMask          = MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_STRING | MIIM_ID | MIIM_SUBMENU;
        mii_menu.fType          = MFT_STRING;
        mii_menu.dwTypeData     = L"File"; 
        mii_menu.cch            = sizeof(L"File");
        mii_menu.wID            = 1;
        mii_menu.hSubMenu   = sub_menu;

    MENUITEMINFO mii_submenu{0};
        mii_submenu.cbSize          = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
        mii_submenu.fMask           = MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_STRING | MIIM_ID | MIIM_STATE | MIIM_CHECKMARKS;
        mii_submenu.fType           = MFT_STRING;
        mii_submenu.fState          = MFS_CHECKED;
        mii_submenu.dwTypeData      = L"Open"; 
        mii_submenu.cch             = sizeof(L"Open");
        mii_submenu.wID             = 2;
        mii_submenu.hbmpChecked     = check;
        mii_submenu.hbmpUnchecked   = uncheck;

    InsertMenuItem(menu,    0, FALSE, &mii_menu);
    InsertMenuItem(sub_menu,0, FALSE, &mii_submenu);

    SetMenu(hWnd, menu);
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg){

        case WM_CREATE:
            funCreateMenu(hWnd);
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY: 
            PostQuitMessage(0); 
        break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
};

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPI, LPWSTR args, int ncmdshow)
{
    g_hInst = hInst;
    LPCWSTR szAppName{L"AppWindows"}, szAppTitle{L"Первая программа!"};

    WNDCLASSEXW wcex{0};
        wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wcex.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
        wcex.cbClsExtra  = 0;
        wcex.cbWndExtra  = 0;
        wcex.hInstance = hInst;
        wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
        wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
        wcex.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
        wcex.lpszClassName = szAppName;
        wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return -1;

    g_hWnd = CreateWindowExW(
        (DWORD)0,
        szAppName,
        szAppTitle, 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 640, 400, 
        nullptr, nullptr, hInst, nullptr);

    MSG msg{0};
    while(GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
};
```

файл resources.h

```
#define ID_MENU_OPEN_CHECK      1
#define ID_MENU_OPEN_UNCHECK    2
```

файл resources.rs

```
#include "resources.h" 

ID_MENU_OPEN_CHECK      BITMAP  DISCARDABLE     "image/check.bmp"
ID_MENU_OPEN_UNCHECK    BITMAP  DISCARDABLE     "image/uncheck.bmp"
```

в папке image
[image: uncheck.bmp]
[image: check.bmp]

выбрал размер 72*72 потому что такое значение вывелось при вызове (std::cout << SM_CXMENUCHECK << " " << SM_CYMENUCHECK << std::endl;), компилю следующим образом

```
windres -o resources.o resources.rs -lunicode
g++ main.cpp resources.o -o main.exe -mwindows -mconsole -municode -lcomctl32
```

но мои иконки не хочет выводить, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SM_CXMENUCHECK` `SM_CYMENUCHECK` - это идентификаторы для получения соответствующих значений из функции `GetSystemMetrics`. Причем один из низ 71, а второй 72. Соответственно вызовы `LoadImage` наверное заканчиваются неудачно, а обработка ошибок у вас отсутствует.

Comment: VTT ваш ответ помог полез менять размер картинок но на этот раз через point а не через gimp и картинки появились, потом поменял на размер 16*16 и при загрузке добавил в ручную 16 и все вывелось ну в маленьком только размере, я так подозреваю что проблема была в параметрах bmp файла когда сохранял их из gimp